# How do I blacklist an address from buying my token

Tags: solidity, remix

Ive been launching degen play contracts and it is being botted by a certain address because he knows that I burn the LP everytime. Is there a way to blacklist this address? Ive seen his wallet and it contains most of the tokens I made. He is also the top holder of almost all of the tokens I made, hence the botting speculation. Keep in mind that he often get 25% of the supply at a low price most of the time.

What should I add in the solidity contract to blacklist this user?

Answer (score 2):

While writing the contract; you can use a mapping to blacklist addresses.

```
contract BlackLkisted is Ownerhip {
    mapping(address=>bool) isBlacklisted;

    function blackList(address _user) public onlyOwner {
        require(!isBlacklisted[_user], "user already blacklisted");
        isBlacklisted[_user] = true;
        // emit events as well
    }
    
    function removeFromBlacklist(address _user) public onlyOwner {
        require(isBlacklisted[_user], "user already whitelisted");
        isBlacklisted[_user] = false;
        // emit events as well
    }
    
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        require(!isBlacklisted[_to], "Recipient is backlisted");
        // remaining transfer logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks. At what part of the contract should I place this code segment and how do I interact with it? THANK YOU!

Comment: Is there anyway i can contact you sir? I really dont have any idea about coding in solidity. I am just forking a code, thats why i dont know where to place that code segment

Comment: Hi; you can reach out to me on skype: prashant23061

Comment: Hey, slight mistake in your code, this will allow only blacklisted addresses to recieve tokens, i believe the intended result is the exact opposite ( `require(!isBlacklisted[_to], "Recipient is backlisted"` , ). Other than that everything works fine, although a modifier would probably be better than just adding a `require` to the transfer function (and would allow you to make it more custom, such as being able to turn the blacklist on or off...) @YawaMan did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: (oops didnt realise this topic was 3 months old lol, sorry)